# SOQL Aggregate calculation error due to multi-currency

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, aggregate, multi-currency

I'm trying to calculate the SUM of all values in my Target__c field, on my Target__c custom object.

When the below code is executed, my debug log shows that updatedTargets contains the correct target record, teamTargetIden contains the correct identifier (a formula field *key*) and targetsToUpdate has contains the correct value (120,000) from the Target__c record (this is the only record with the selected identifier).

But the SOQL SUM produces a figure of 178,491.74 and I can't work out why?

```
trigger MonthlyTeamTargetCal on Target__c (after insert, after update) {

    List<Target__c> updatedTargets = new list<Target__c>();
    for (Target__c t : Trigger.New){

        try{
            Target__c oldT = Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id);
            if(oldT.Target__c != t.Target__c)
            {
                updatedTargets.add(t);
            }
        //if old.Map is null, record has been inserted & (re)calculation should be done
        }catch(System.NullPointerException e){
            updatedTargets.add(t);
        }
    }
    system.debug('updatedTargets contains ' + updatedTargets);

    If(updatedTargets.size() > 0){

    //create a set of Identifiers, which will be used to select Target records to update
    Set<String> teamTargetIden = new Set<String>();
    for(Target__c t : updatedTargets){
        teamTargetIden.add(t.Team_MT_Identifier__c);
    }
        system.debug('teamTargetIden contains ' + teamTargetIden);

    List<Target__c> targetsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Target__c FROM Target__c
                                        WHERE Team_MT_Identifier__c IN :teamTargetIden];

        system.debug('targetsToUpdate contains ' + targetsToUpdate);

    Decimal mnthlyTeamTarget = (Decimal) [SELECT SUM(Target__c) sum FROM Target__c
                                           WHERE Id IN :targetsToUpdate][0].get('sum');

    system.debug('mnthlyTeamTarget contains ' + mnthlyTeamTarget);

    for(Target__c t : targetsToUpdate){
        t.Team_Target__c = mnthlyTeamTarget;
    }
    update targetsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The calculation works fine if the record currency is set to my org's corporate currency.

[image]

My record's currency is GBP and the conversion rate we're using from USD:GBP is 0.672300.

How can I manage this in the calculation, to allow the use of multiple currencies?

Comment: Can you try typecast it into Integer instead of Decimal

Comment: I've only changed this line, as follows     Integer mnthlyTeamTarget = (Integer) [SELECT SUM(Target__c) sum FROM Target__c
                                           WHERE Team_MT_Identifier__c IN :teamTargetIden][0].get('Sum'); but this then causes an error 'Invalid conversion from runtime type Decimal to Integer'

Comment: Use Integer.valueOf(); function then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the function, where should I use it?

Comment: This way `Integer mnthlyTeamTarget = Integer.valueOf([SELECT SUM(Target__c) sum FROM Target__c
                                           WHERE Team_MT_Identifier__c IN :teamTargetIden][0].get('Sum')); `

Comment: Thanks, no errors but the calculation produced the same incorrect figure (without the decimal points obviously).

Comment: One reason might be that this trigger is only including records where `Target__c > 0` and your other calculation is including negative values.

Comment: @KeithC thanks for the suggestion, the flow of my code didn't make a lot of sense and I've also removed that line but the error's still occurring. I've just seen that the issue's due to the record currency not matching my org's default currency, I'll update my question but I'm still not sure how to solve the issue.

Comment: At least you know why now - always an important step. Perhaps you could add the multi-currency tag and maybe add that in the title if thats the key factor?

Comment: I should be able to solve the issue with [this solution](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008y4vIAA), just trying to update the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact that the Target__c record's currency was GBP, while my org's corporate currency is USD.

Since convertCurrency() [can't](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000b1lLAAQ) be combined with the aggregate function, I had to use the solution on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008y4vIAA) post, to convert the value from the Target__c field, to produce the following

```
trigger MonthlyTeamTargetCal on Target__c (after insert, after update) {

    List<Target__c> updatedTargets = new list<Target__c>();
    Set<String> teamTargetIden = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> targetCurrency = new Set<String>();

    for (Target__c t : Trigger.New){

        try{
            Target__c oldT = Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id);
            if(oldT.Target__c != t.Target__c)
            {
                updatedTargets.add(t);
                teamTargetIden.add(t.Team_MT_Identifier__c);
                targetCurrency.add(t.CurrencyIsoCode);
            }
        //if old.Map is null, record has been inserted & (re)calculation should be done
        }catch(System.NullPointerException e){
            updatedTargets.add(t);
            teamTargetIden.add(t.Team_MT_Identifier__c);
            targetCurrency.add(t.CurrencyIsoCode);
        }
    }

    if(updatedTargets.size() > 0){

    List<Target__c> targetsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Target__c FROM Target__c
                                        WHERE Team_MT_Identifier__c IN :teamTargetIden];

        system.debug('targetsToUpdate contains ' + targetsToUpdate);

    Decimal mnthlyTeamTarget = (Decimal) [SELECT SUM(Target__c) sum FROM Target__c
                                           WHERE Id IN :targetsToUpdate][0].get('sum');

        if(targetCurrency.contains('USD') == false){

            Decimal conversionRate = [SELECT conversionrate FROM currencytype 
                                       WHERE isocode = :targetCurrency LIMIT 1].conversionRate;

            for(Target__c t : targetsToUpdate){
                t.Team_Target__c = mnthlyTeamTarget*conversionRate;
            }

        }else{
            for(Target__c t : targetsToUpdate){
                t.Team_Target__c = mnthlyTeamTarget;
            }
        }
        update targetsToUpdate;
    }
}
```